# Why adding Image changes the position of parent <div> or <span>?

Tags: html, css

Please tell me why adding image **via img tag** change the position of parent container.

```
<div id="dives" class="rex">
    <span class="ex"><img class="img1" src="logo.png"></span><span class="ex2"></span><span class="ex3"></span>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GATA/QD78K/)

But when I add "display:block" (Thanks to *Dark Ashelin*) it work again.

```
img.img1{
padding:0;
margin:0px auto;
display: block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GATA/NF7A2/)

Does anyone know why this happen and why adding "display:block" corrects it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.First of all always close the img tag

2.style="width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid blue;"

put this in your code in your span and div and you will come to know the problem.This problems happen bcoz of size of div ans span img are diff by bordering you come to know the overlapping.

This code is correct just add float property actually what is happing is when u are placing another element inside span it is placing it adjacent to it float will put it on the prev element.

```
<div id="dives" class="rex" style="border:solid red">
    <span class="ex"><img class="img1" src="logo.png" style="float:left"/></span><span class="ex2"></span><span class="ex3"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) that made it easier.

Comment: This code is correct just add float property actually what is happing is when u are placing another element inside span it is placing it adjacent to it float will put it on the prev element.

Comment: As you can see I am noob :) What I have learned so far is to not overuse "float" property. Is it normal to use it like this.

Comment: I develop websites and there is a lot of use of float.However it is problemetic but i have given u the solution of bordering.You can also use the property of position also if u dont want to use float.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the parent has the position property omitted, then the child would be positioned relative to the next containing div with a relative or absolute position. If no containing elements have these position properties set on the page, then the child will be positioned relative to the page body

Comment: Thank you, would you please explain a little more. I tried to set the position property but it didn't stop image from moving away.

Comment: The one key thing to remember when trying to position a child relative to it’s parent is that the child should be given the CSS property position:absolute; and the parent set to either position:absolute; or position:relative;. Other positioning styles for position:fixed; and position:inherit; may also work in some cases but will rarely be required.

Comment: @GATA, you may also look a bit here : http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/. Just remember that for display the default value is inline for all members.

Answer (score 1):

set image position

```
img.img1{
padding:0;
margin:0px auto;
position: absolute;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QD78K/1/)

Comment: Thank you AJ This was instructive. but still I cant understand why this happens.

Comment: He is also write making position absolute will place the element where ever u will give the coordinates by default it is relative so it will flow on the body of browser like text.

Comment: Yes now I get it but I thought making position absolute will trow that element out of the normal flow.Is this safe? Wouldn't it cause inconsistency?

Comment: No sir, with position AJ has also mentioned padding and all.But u are correct for long coding like developing website u have to make a lot of change in design at that time u should know what element u have declared absolute and relative.

Answer (score 1):

Because a span is an inline element (display: inline) by standard. An image is display: inline-block. Inside inline elements it is only allowed to put other inline elements, nothing else! So, if you make `display: block;` on your span tag, it becomes a block element. Inside block elements (div is block) you can put any other kind of element.

Instead of using CSS with `display: block;` I would rather use a div instead of span.

Comment: Thanks Anthony but <div> also has this problem. it must be something else I think.

Comment: his problem is of position and overlapping and display:block is used if u want display next element in a newline.